# How to play an external audio file with javascript not Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to play sounds with JavaScript, for example I want to play this sound `sounds/main.mp3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by defining your audio file.

Then you can call it where you want in your scripts with play().

```
var myAudio = new Audio('sounds/main.mp3');
myAudio.play();
```